# Dynamic casting nodes in BST

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have got a class

```
class Para{
public:
    int wrt, liczbaWystapien;
    Para(int wrt, int liczbaWystapien){
        this->wrt = wrt;
        this->liczbaWystapien = liczbaWystapien;
    }...
```

And the BST tree template in which I have insert_helper function and the error with dynamic cast

```
void insertHelper(Node<T>* node, T value){
        if(value < node->key){
            if(node->left == NULL)
                node->left = new Node<T>(value);
            else
                insertHelper(node->left, value);
        }
        else if(value > node->key){//bez duplikatow bad z duplikatami
            if(node->right == NULL)
                node->right = new Node<T>(value);
            else
                insertHelper(node->right, value);
        }else if (is_same<T, Para*>::value){
            //cout<<"PARA fsaifhsaiohfoasihfaoih"<<endl;
            dynamic_cast<BST<Para*>>(node)->key->wrt++;//HERE IS ERROR
        }
    }
```

The inscance of tree is:

```
BST<Para*>* bstLicznosc;
```

How to correct this dynamic cast(I need any kind of cast)?

EDIT:

When I use:

```
dynamic_cast<BST<Para*>*>(node)->key->wrt++;
```

I get:

```
Error   4   error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'Node<T>' is not a polymorphic type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only `dynamic_cast` to reference or pointer types, i.e. to `BST<Para*>&` or to `BST<Para*>*`, not to `BST<Para*>`.

In your case, `BST<Para*>*` is correct, because `node` is a pointer.

Furthermore, `node` must be of a polymorphic type, i.e. it must have a virtual function (the destructor is a good candidate).

Comment: @user1825608 I did and added to my answer.